# Flutter Bloc: How to implement bloc to bloc communication

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, rxdart

n project I have a Home page(with list of movie data) with HomeBloc. On clicking the a single movie cell I navigate to movie details page which has MovieDetailsBloc. Now in the details page I can edit name or make movie as favourite etc, this needs to be reflected in Home page.

To update the Home page after a change in Movie details page, I am sending HomeBloc to Movie details page like this

```
MovieDetailsPage(homeBloc: <instance of HomeBloc>)
```

and in the MovieDetailsBloc I am calling the event of HomeBloc to update the Home page like this

```
homeBlocInstance.add(<home event>)
```

This method is working.

My question is Is this good method like passing bloc to a page? There will be many places from where this Home page may need to be updated. For example

Make changes in settings -> Update home page
In this case should I pass the Home bloc to settings page? But what if the navigation is like this Home page -> Summary page -> settings page, should I keep passing the HomeBloc from Home page to Summary page and then settings page? This does not seem right.

Am i doing it right?

or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `GoRouter`, When you're navigate back to home, you can just pass param to the router state, so when you are `go` to homepage you can do some process.

For example :

```
context.goNamed(
  'home',
   queryParams:{
     'somestate': 'somevalue',
     'somesetting': 'settingValue',
   },
);
```

Comment: I am not using GoRouter. I wanted to know if there is any solution using bloc itself.